# Consequence Vitali covering lemma

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real valued function and put
$$A=\{x\in(a,b)\colon f\text{ is differentiable at }x,\; f'(x)=0\}.$$

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$, then the following holds:

1. Let $\varepsilon>0$, $\alpha>0$ and $y\in f[A]$, then there exists an $x\in A$ and $\delta>0$ such that$$\forall a\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)\colon f(a)\in[y-\delta\varepsilon, y+\delta\varepsilon]$$ and $$\lambda\big([y-\delta\varepsilon, y+\delta\varepsilon]\big)<\alpha.$$
2. Vitali's covering lemma implies that $\lambda^*(f[A])=0$, where $\lambda^*$ denote the Lebesgue outer measure.

Vitali's Covering lemma is stated as

> Let $E$ be a set of finite Lebesgue outer measure and $\mathcal{F}$ a
>   collection of intervals the that $E$ in the sense of Vitali. Then, for
>   all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a finite disjoint collection
>   $\{I_1,\ldots, I_n\}$ such that
>   $$\lambda^*\left(E\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k\right)<\varepsilon.$$

I was wondering if anyone knows how to prove these two statements. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thank you for giving us this information.   However, this site is for asking questions, not for stating theorems.

Comment: Maybe it's sleep deprivation, but that comment made me laugh aloud for an entire minute (@GEdgar)!

Comment: It might be useful to state which version of the Vitali covering lemma you are referencing.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a partial solution!**

For the first part:

Let $y\in A$, $\varepsilon>0$ and $\alpha>0$, then there is a $x\in A$ such that
$y=f(x)$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $x$, there  is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|u-x|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{f(u)-f(x)}{u-x}-f'(x)\right|\le\varepsilon.$$
Using that $f'(x)=0$, $$f(x)-\varepsilon|u-x|\le f(u)\le f(x)+\varepsilon|u-x|.$$
So $f(u)\in[y-\delta\varepsilon, y+\delta\epsilon]$.
Because  $\varepsilon$ was given arbitriraly and any smaller $\delta$ suffices, the measure of the interval $[y-\delta\varepsilon, y+\delta\varepsilon]$ made less than $\alpha$.

This is the appropriate Vitali covering lemma:

> Let $E$ be a set of finite outer measure and $\mathcal{F}$ a
>   collection of closed intervals that cover $E$ in the Vitali sense,
>   that is for any $\alpha>0$ there and $x\in E$ there is an interval
>   $I\in\mathcal{F}$ such that length$(I)<\alpha$.

Note that  the collection
$$\mathcal{F}=\{I(y,\alpha)=[y-\delta\varepsilon, y+\delta\varepsilon]\colon \mathrm{length}(I(y,\alpha))<\alpha, y\in f[A]\}$$ is clearly a Vitali cover for $f[A]$ by part 1.
Unfortunately, $f[A]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which doesn't have finite outer measure.

I don't know how to continu onwards. I guess that you need to consider for $R>0$ sufficiently large, the set $$E=f[A]\cap[-R,R]$$ and assume that $\lambda^*(E)>0$. This might lead to a contradiction.

*Is there someone with a helpful suggestion?*